# What does it mean upon budgetary approval?

Tags: job-search, job, faculty-application, tenure-track

I was going through one advertisement for the Tenure track position. The job advertisement has written something like this: What does it mean?

Effective Date of Appointment: August 23, 2023 (Subject to Budgetary Approval)

Answer (score 5):

It means *somewhere* some budget isn’t finalized so there a chance nobody is hired because the money for the position never materialized, or the date of appointment may be pushed back because not *all* the money materialized.

This is a pretty standard disclaimer clause and so not much to worry about.  It does happen that positions are pulled because of budgetary issues but *rarely*, and when this happens the university has the black eye since such actions are likely to impact future recruitment efforts. I mean: if you advertise X years in a row and the position is always pulled, who will apply in year X+1?

Comment: Right. Basically at our uni they can cancel the search at any point, but usually when they have done so the cancellation only applies to positions where no offer has been made. So it is always an incentive for our department to move as quickly as possible!

Answer (score 3):

It means that the job might be offered or not, depending on money being available. It is an ad for a "possible" position, but not a definite one.

This is probably necessitated by uncertainty of various kinds, such as legislative action at a US State university.

They can't make a definite offer, most likely, until the uncertainty is resolved, but they can look at candidates.

If the place and the position are interesting enough then it might be worth considering, but don't give up other opportunities "hoping" it will work out.

Comment: so the budget typically is on june/july, so even if I get the offer it will not be finalized until june/july ? why candidates would be interested in such jobs !!!

Comment: What a waste of time.  In many cases, they would ask for letters of recommendation as well.

Comment: You probably won't get an offer. They might express strong interest. Don't put off other opportunities, of course.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus, their alternative might need to be waiting for the next cycle. Sub-optimal at best.

Comment: @Chobi I don't know where you are applying, but in most places in the US the alternative would be to just fire you ("lay off") before you've even started, and there's nothing illegal about that - if there's no money to pay you with they don't need to pay you, the only thing you legally need to be paid for is work you've actually done. When interviewing I'd recommend asking about the budget prospects, it's possible it's a disclaimer for a rare event or it's possible that it's a stretch to fund the position at all.

Comment: In my state the legislature alternates between a 30-day session in January and a 60-day session in January-February. So with the normal faculty hiring rhythm they would prep an add and start advertising before the session. Often with good odds on the funding being approved, but it isn’t guaranteed.

Comment: @JonCuster +1 for the good odds.

Comment: @JonCuster so at your institution, funds got approval in February ?

Comment: The final budgets for state universities get approved in January or February of each year, yes. I'm not at a state university, so my institutions fiscal year is different. But I still know the legislature calendar...